# Deserializing JSON containing an empty array becomes null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm attempting to deserialize the following JSON:

```
{
    "ListA":[],
    "ListB":
    [
        {
            "Item1":{"Id":"-1"}
        }
    ]
}
```

ListB deserializes correctly, but ListA just deserializes to null; I'd prefer it to deserialize to an empty list.

My code to deserialize this JSON is as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
settings.Binder = new TypeNameSerializationBinder(modelBindingTypeAssembliesFactory);
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jsonContent), settings);
```

Any ideas? I would have thought that the correct behavior would be that [] becomes an empty list.

Comment: An empty list of what?  Objects?  Strings?  With no data the deserializer has no idea what type of list to create.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `MyType` ?

Comment: I also wanted this feature a while back. I ended up validating the nullness of my list each time I used it, which was not a big deal.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I took your classes, pasted them into http://json2csharp.com/, renamed `RootObject` to `MyType`, then deserialized your JSON using the classes and your code -- except that I don't have your `modelBindingTypeAssembliesFactory` so I had do delete the `settings.Binder = ...` line.  When I did, `ListA` was deserialized as an empty list, not a null list.  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?